# Odd Yaesu CAT command of MS which the docs name as "Meter SW"

Tags: yaesu, computer-control

This is for the FTDX10 but I suspect this MS command is also there for other Yaesu rigs.
This is NOT the command to read the Po/S/SWR/ALC/etc meters as the RM (Read Meter) command is used for that.  RM is only a read operation there is no set option for RM, which makes perfect sense.

But the MS command can be set also.  The [manual](https://usermanual.wiki/m/f8a95a74dfc68ca2ae99c7c29a6636aa36a507dcd9636b5ade78a8eb69d90492.pdf) shows on pg 16 that this MS command also does have something to do with the Po/S/SWR/ALC/Comp/etc meters but I just cannot figure this out.  I asked Yaesu tech support about this and while they have in the past been very helpful in any questions, instead they just said "Im not a programmer".

I figured Id ask here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this command may be used to switch (Meter SW = meter switch?) between the different options for the parameter that can be displayed by the meter (power, compression, ALC, voltage, current, SWR). The SET variant of the command will switch to the desired parameter, while the READ variant will return which parameter is currently displayed (it does not return the value of the displayed parameter, as this is done by the RM command).

Answer (score 1):

Its meters are on screen and selectable via soft menus as opposed to a hard knob (the multipurpose Func knob is used to select).

The MS command SWitches(sic) the actively displayed Menu.

Comment: Yes, confirmed by looking at the hamlib driver. The MS command is used to get/set `RIG_LEVEL_METER` which is a discrete with options for SWR/Comp/ALC/Po/Vd/Id/Temp.

Comment: Thanks for the confirm! I've edited my answer to remove the weasel words.